# Make Important Files a Different Color in bash terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I have my `~/.bashrc` and `~/.dircolors` files setup so I can customize the colors of extension.

### .dircolors

`file.py 01;35`

Is it possible to differentiate priority files with the same extension

### Example

`important_file.py` shows up as red

`unimportant_file.py` shows up as white

Comment: That depends; how are you defining important files?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dircolors-invocation.html#dircolors-invocation) and [`man 5 dircolors`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/dir_colors.5.html) and the output of `dircolors --print-database`, you can only set colours per file extension.

Comment: @chepner My definition is an arbitrary decision. Any solution would work (adding a prefix/suffix to the file, manipulating group permissions, having a list of important files, etc.)